# Why is the pdf() function bringing out an error when I run it?

Tags: r, graphics

```
library(gridGraphics)
pdf("figures/marketvalue-sales.pdf", version = "1.4")
plot(log(marketvalue) ~ log(sales), data = Forbes2000, col = rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1), pch = 16)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to the [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to revise your question. As of now, there's no way for anyone to reproduce your error and provide any insights to your issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'figures' directory doesn't exist, this will give an error. You can only save files into existing directories.